# Am I allowed to take files I created off someone else's computer?

Tags: intellectual-property

I recently created a website for a friend of mine, but after some issues between the two of us I decided to remote control their computer (which I had permission to do) and took the files off.

- Am I allowed to do so?
- Are the files my intellectual property that I have rights to?

I'm quite young and don't quite understand a lot of legal 'stuff.'

Comment: Did you create these files? What's the agreement regarding remote control between you too?

Comment: @Viktor Yes, I created and put all the content they had into them. Our agreement is that I can connect depending on what I'm doing. I had connected, began working on the files, then the aforementioned "issues" occurred, and I made the decision to remove the files and end the session. I had permission to conduct that session, as they were at the computer when I connected, and did not disconnect me or revoke my access during that session in any way.

Comment: My impression is: your position is not the strongest (at first look); as the facts you admit to raise serious questions. Most importantly: you took files off someone else's computer without explicit permission to take the files. I'm assuming because you're asking this question that your counterparty will not just sign a waiver and grant you ownership of all the files and release you from liability, correct? Will they claim that some of the work on those files was theirs? If so, would they agree to a mutual agreement that you both can retain your own individual copies of those files?

Comment: @Mowzer "Will they claim that some of the work on those files was theirs?" No, as we've resolved our issues and they have re-granted me access to continue working, and I've put the files back in their original positions on the drive, and they haven't touched the files at all, even from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about the user account that you used when you created the files ie the owner.

Assuming there was no written contract between you and your friend which might override the default circumstances:

- If you or your friend has created a user account for you on his computer/server then ***you have the right to do whatever you want/can with the files you create*** as long as you don't override the access control rules (ie the privileges assigned to your account by the OS) by exploiting some privileges escalation vulnerability.
- If you used somebody's else account to create the files then you have a very small chance proving that the files contents are actually yours and you have the copyrights for them and you decided to take action and remove them instead of complaining to the authorities which might reduce the punishment for the unauthorized act you performed on your friends computer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the facts you describe might or might not create a problem for you.

My sense of things is the best course of action might be to try and negotiate a settlement regarding the disposition of the files in question.

See my comments.

Comment: Thanks Mowzer, I've replied to the comment. We've resolved the aforementioned 'issues,' and are back to working on the files as before. I'll retain all the information gained from this question for further reference, as it's all quite useful so far.